# Sync scroll react. div block with main scroll on window

Tags: reactjs, scroll, react-hooks

I want to synchronize a divs scroll with a body scroll.

I tried some examples with two divs but I couldn't manage fix it with the body scroll.

Sample code with two divs: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-custom-scroll-sync-of-2-divs-10xpi

**My Code**

https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-rain-ditbv

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const firstDivRef = useRef();
  const secondDivRef = useRef();

  const handleScrollFirst = (scroll) => {
    secondDivRef.current.scrollTop = scroll.target.scrollTop;
  };

  const handleScrollSecond = (scroll) => {
    firstDivRef.current.scrollTop = scroll.target.scrollTop;
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="App"
      style={{
        display: "flex",
   
   
    
      }}
    >
      <div
        onScroll={handleScrollFirst}
        ref={firstDivRef}
        style={{
          height: "500px",
          overflow: "scroll",
          backgroundColor: "#FFDAB9",
          position: "sticky",
          top: "0px"
        }}
      >
        <div style={{ height: 5000, width: 300 }}>
          The first div (or it can be tbody of a table and etc.)
          {[...new Array(1000)].map((_, index) => {
            const isEven = index % 2 === 0;
            return (
              <div style={{ backgroundColor: isEven ? "#FFFFE0  " : "#FFDAB9" }}>
                {index}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div
        onScroll={handleScrollSecond}
        ref={secondDivRef}
        style={{
          height: "100%",

          backgroundColor: "#EEE8AA"
        }}
      >
        <div style={{ height: 5000, width: 200 }}>
          The second div
          {[...new Array(1000)].map((_, index) => {
            const isEven = index % 2 === 0;
            return (
              <div style={{ backgroundColor: isEven ? "#FFFFE0  " : "#FFDAB9" }}>
                {index}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You want us to make it for you? What have you tried, where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @kevin  I tried to use this code , but it works with two div block, not with main scroll               import React, {useRef} from 'react'; 
  const firstDivRef = useRef();
  const secondDivRef = useRef();
 
  const handleScrollFirst = (scroll) => {
    secondDivRef.current.scrollTop = scroll.target.scrollTop;
  };
  const handleScrollSecond = (scroll) => {
    firstDivRef.current.scrollTop = scroll.target.scrollTop;
  };
  <div
      onScroll={handleScrollFirst}
      ref={firstDivRef}></div>   <div
      onScroll={handleScrollSecond}
      ref={secondDivRef}></div>

Comment: @kevin And also tried to use this dependencies   "react-scroll"
    "react-scroll-sync"
    "react-use-sync-scroll"

Comment: Please share your code in your question. Try to use codesandbox to show us what you have, and what is wrong about it. Otherwise, we can't help you.

Comment: @hurricane Thanks , i didnt know how to put code here. I tried to use this code https://codesandbox.io/s/react-custom-scroll-sync-of-2-divs-10xpi . I didnt write any code on the main  project. Just was testing on draft project by  using useEffect , but coudnt connet them . I delete previous code becasuse i tested too much. And i have only this code on above

Comment: @TinatinOmurova So it does work on the sandbox. You need to show the sample you did and explain what is wrong or what do you want to have right?

Comment: @hurricane it`s the same code. Just want to rewrite. If you notice there is a sync scroll of two blocks. But i want to sync one div scroll with window scroll https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-rain-ditbv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was easy to use different divs rather than using a div and window.

But finally managed to run it with a div and the body.

The trick is they block each other since they listen each others values.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const firstDivRef = useRef();

  const [scrollTop, setScrollTop] = useState(0);
  const [disableBodyScroll, setDisableBodyScroll] = useState(false);
  const handleScrollFirst = (scroll) => {
    setScrollTop(scroll.target.scrollTop);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (firstDivRef.current && !disableBodyScroll) {
      firstDivRef.current.scrollTop = scrollTop;
    }
    if (disableBodyScroll) {
      window.scrollTo(0, scrollTop);
    }
  }, [firstDivRef, scrollTop, disableBodyScroll]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const onScroll = () => {
      console.log(disableBodyScroll, window.scrollY);

      if (!disableBodyScroll) {
        setScrollTop(window.scrollY);
      }
    };
    // clean up code
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
    window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
  }, [disableBodyScroll]);

  return (
    <div
      className="App"
      style={{
        display: "flex"
      }}
    >
      <div
        onMouseEnter={() => setDisableBodyScroll(true)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setDisableBodyScroll(false)}
        onScroll={handleScrollFirst}
        ref={firstDivRef}
        style={{
          height: "500px",
          overflow: "scroll",
          backgroundColor: "#FFDAB9",
          position: "sticky",
          top: "0px"
        }}
      >
        <div style={{ height: 5000, width: 300 }}>
          The first div (or it can be tbody of a table and etc.)
          {[...new Array(1000)].map((_, index) => {
            const isEven = index % 2 === 0;
            return (
              <div style={{ backgroundColor: isEven ? "#FFFFE0  " : "#FFDAB9" }}>
                {index}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div
        style={{
          height: "100%",

          backgroundColor: "#EEE8AA"
        }}
      >
        <div style={{ height: 5000, width: 200 }}>
          The second div
          {[...new Array(1000)].map((_, index) => {
            const isEven = index % 2 === 0;
            return (
              <div style={{ backgroundColor: isEven ? "#FFFFE0  " : "#FFDAB9" }}>
                {index}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-dream-tzuel?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank You everyone! I` m so happy. You solved my problem that i couldnt solve for a long time. I used this code for real project.

Comment: @TinatinOmurova Don't forget to approve the correct answer. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Try the next example. This is a quick sketch but maybe it will help you.

`https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-goldwasser-19g4d?file=/src/App.js`

Comment: Thank you. You helped me a lot!